# Runaway Energies for MD Simulation Using Verlet Algorithm with Periodic Boundary Conditions

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a very basic MD simulation code in C++ for a system of 125 particles in a 30x30x30 box with periodic boundary conditions. I have succeeded in initializing the box, but whenever I run the code over multiple time steps the energies blow up and the positions don't fall within the box for certain particles. I am fairly certain it is a problem with the periodic boundary conditions, but I cannot figure out what the problem is. I have attached my code below and would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

```
/******************************************************************************************************************************************
 * Program:
 * Create MD simulation for small system of particles
 ******************************************************************************************************************************************/

//include
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int N; //number of particles
int l; //length of box
double T; //temp
double dt; //time step
double m; //mass
int nsteps; //number of time steps

//properties of lj potential
double sigma;
double rcut;
double ecut;
double ep;

double K; //kinetic energy of system
double Kp; //I have a time delay in the KE calculation so I need to store the value
double energy; //energy

//vector with position data
std::vector<std::vector<double> > r;
//vector with previous position data
std::vector<std::vector<double> > rp;
//vector with velocity data
std::vector<std::vector<double> > v;
//vector with force data
std::vector<std::vector<double> > f;
//vector with acceleration data
std::vector<std::vector<double> > a;
//vector to store position difference between two steps
std::vector<std::vector<double> > dr2t;

void init_pos(int l, int N);
void init_vel(int N, double T, double dt);
void force(int N, double dt);
void accel(double m);
void integrate(double dt);
void vel(double dt);


int main () {

  // simulation parameters
  N = 125;
  l = 30;
  T = 0.3;
  dt = 0.001;
  m = 1;
  nsteps = 501;

  //properties of lj potential
  sigma = 1;
  rcut = 3.5*sigma;
  ep = 1;
  ecut = 4*ep*(pow((sigma/rcut),12.0) - pow((sigma/rcut),6.0));

  //initialize the positions and velocities
  init_pos(l,N);
  init_vel(N,T,dt);

  //open file to store positions
  FILE * out_pos;
  out_pos = fopen("Shea_positions.dat", "w");

  //open file to store energy info
  FILE * out_en;
  out_en = fopen("Shea_energy.dat", "w");

  //header in pos file for time step 0
  fprintf(out_pos, "%d \n", N);
  fprintf(out_pos, "Time Step: 0 \n");

  //print positions of each particle
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {

    fprintf(out_pos, "%d %f %f %f\n", i, r[i][0], r[i][1], r[i][2]);

  }

  //time loop to perform multiple steps
  for (int t=1; t<nsteps; t++) {

    //header in file for each time step
    //fprintf(out_pos, "\n");
    fprintf(out_pos, "%d \n", N);
    fprintf(out_pos, "Time Step: \t%d \n", t);

    Kp = K; //kinetic energy of system at current time step (calculated in next time step after initialization)

    //perform calculations at each time step
    force(N, dt);
    accel(m);
    integrate(dt);
    vel(dt);

    //print positions of each particle
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {

      fprintf(out_pos, "%d %f %f %f\n", i, r[i][0], r[i][1], r[i][2]);

    }

  //output to energy file
    fprintf(out_en, "%d %f %f %f\n", t-1, energy, Kp, energy+Kp);


  }

    fclose(out_pos);
    fclose(out_en);  

}


/*********************************************************************************************************************************/

//function to initialize positions

void init_pos(int l, int N) {

  int n = (int) cbrt(N); //number of particles in row
  int a = 1; //lattice spacing
  r.resize(N, std::vector<double>(3, 0));


  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
      for (int k=0; k<n; k++) {

        int num_part = i*n*n+j*n+k;
        r[num_part][0] = i*a-n/2*a;
        r[num_part][1] = j*a-n/2*a;
        r[num_part][2] = k*a-n/2*a;

      }
    }
  }

}

/*********************************************************************************************************************************/

//function to initialize velocities

void init_vel(int N, double T, double dt) {
  int RANDMAX=10000;
  rp.resize(N, std::vector<double>(3, 0));
  v.resize(N, std::vector<double>(3, 0));
  std::vector<double> vcom(3, 0);
  double sumv2 = 0;

  K=0; //initialize kinetic energy at 0

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (int alpha=0; alpha<3; alpha++) {
      v[i][alpha] = ((double)(rand() % RANDMAX) / RANDMAX)-0.5; //assign random velocities from -0.5 to 0.5
      vcom[alpha] += v[i][alpha]; //calculate the com velocity
      sumv2 += v[i][alpha]*v[i][alpha];

    }
  }

  for (int alpha=0; alpha<3; alpha++) {
    vcom[alpha] /= N; //translational velocity of system to remove
  }

  sumv2 = sumv2/N; //average KE per particle
  double sf = sqrt(3*T/(sumv2)); //scaling factor

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (int alpha=0; alpha<3; alpha++) {
      v[i][alpha] -= vcom[alpha]; //correct for com velocity
      v[i][alpha] *= sf; //multiply by scaling factor to give the correct temp
      rp[i][alpha] = r[i][alpha] - v[i][alpha]*dt; //calculate the previous position

    }

  K += 0.5*m*(v[i][0]*v[i][0]+v[i][1]*v[i][1]+v[i][2]*v[i][2]); //find total kinetic energy of the system

  }   

}

/*********************************************************************************************************************************/

//calculate force on each particle from the lj potential

void force(int N, double dt) {

  f.resize(N, std::vector<double>(3, 0));
  energy = 0.;

  std::vector<double> dr(3, 0);
  double dr2;

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {

      //calculate distance vector between two particles
      dr[0] = r[i][0]-r[j][0];
      dr[1] = r[i][1]-r[j][1];
      dr[2] = r[i][2]-r[j][2];

      //make sure pbc works by taking minimum dist between particles i and j
      dr[0] -= l*round(dr[0]/l);
      dr[1] -= l*round(dr[1]/l);
      dr[2] -= l*round(dr[2]/l);

      dr2 = dr[0]*dr[0] + dr[1]*dr[1] + dr[2]*dr[2]; //distance between particles i and j squared


      if(dr2<rcut*rcut) {
        double invr2 = 1./dr2;
        double invr6 = invr2*invr2*invr2;
        double ff = 48.* invr2*invr6*(invr6-0.5); //modulus of the force on a particle

        //add force to particle i
        f[i][0] += ff*dr[0];
        f[i][1] += ff*dr[1];
        f[i][2] += ff*dr[2];

        //add equal and oppostie force to particle j  
        f[j][0] -= ff*dr[0];
        f[j][1] -= ff*dr[1];
        f[j][2] -= ff*dr[2];

        //calculate the potential energy of the particle
        energy += 4*invr6*(invr6-1)-ecut;

      }

    }
  }

}

/*********************************************************************************************************************************/

//calculate the acceleration of the particle from the force

void accel(double m) {

  a.resize(N, std::vector<double>(3, 0));

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (int alpha=0; alpha<3; alpha++) {
      a[i][alpha] = f[i][alpha]/m;

    }
  }
}

/*********************************************************************************************************************************/

//integrate to get the new position of the particle after one time step

void integrate(double dt) {

  dr2t.resize(N, std::vector<double>(3, 0));

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {

    for (int alpha=0; alpha<3; alpha++) {

      double rr = 2*r[i][alpha] - rp[i][alpha] + dt*dt*a[i][alpha]; //new pos from velocity verlet alg
     printf("%f %f %f \n", rr,r[i][alpha],rp[i][alpha]);
//printf("%f \n", a[i][alpha]);
      if (rr >= l/2) {
        rr -= l;
      }
      if (rr < -l/2) {
        rr += l;
      }

      dr2t[i][alpha] = rr - rp[i][alpha]; //difference between new position and previous position so you can find velocity
      dr2t[i][alpha] -= l*round(dr2t[i][alpha]/l);

      rp[i][alpha] = r[i][alpha]; //current position becomes previous position
      r[i][alpha] = rr; //new position becomes current positions

    }     

  }

}

/*********************************************************************************************************************************/

//velocity

void vel(double dt) {

  K = 0;

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for (int alpha=0; alpha<3; alpha++) {

  //printf("%f %f %f \n", dr2t[i][0], dr2t[i][1], dr2t[i][2]);

      v[i][alpha] = dr2t[i][alpha]/(2*dt);

    }

  K += 0.5*m*(v[i][0]*v[i][0]+v[i][1]*v[i][1]+v[i][2]*v[i][2]);

  }

}

/*********************************************************************************************************************************/
```

Comment: Problem is usually that floating point physics is inexact and small errors accumulate.  Either use scaled integers or add a small dampening factor.

Comment: One way to diagnose is to check the percentage of the total energy each particle has. If only one grows, output values and debug it. If they all grow regularly, just normalize, adjusting them by the same factor so that total energy remains constant.

Comment: The problem is that your potential is singular. The Verlet method only works well when the potential is smooth. So whenever two particles pass very closely, unspeakable things happen to the energy. To some extend this can be reduced by reducing the step size, but the general problem persists.